# Flutter - how to get widget count on integration test

Tags: flutter, integration-testing

how can i get the widget count

```
final SerializableFinder finder = find.byType('MyWidget');
await driver.tap(finder);
```

but MyWidget may be more than one,
that will throw exception

Comment: Did you figured it out?

Answer (score 5):

You will need to use some attribute that allows you to find the widget you need. For example, add a `Key` to each of these widgets, so it's easier to find the one you need:

`...MyWidget(key: Key('myWidget1'))...`

So, find it by key:

`find.byKey(Key('myWidget1'))`

If you want to find the widget count, you can use this:

```
final finder = find.byType(MyWidget, skipOffstage: false); // Without quotes!
final count = tester.widgetList<MyWidget>(finder).length;
```